# Android: How to Convert ArrayList values to String

Tags: android, string, email, arraylist

In my app i want to send the ListView items to email body. For that i want that convert ArrayList values to String. Here is my code:

```
            String[] namesArr = new String[array_list.size()];
             String finalStr="";
            for (int i = 0; i < array_list.size(); i++) {
                namesArr[i] = array_list.get(i);  

            }
            System.out.println("finalstr=" +namesArr);
```

I just want to display my Listview items to my email body part. Please suggest me the way to do so. I want to convert all the values to single string so that i can send it as a List to email.
Thank You.

Comment: Do you want to convert all the values to a single string?

Comment: Yes i want to convert all the values to single string.

Comment: your question is not clear. use `finalStr+=array_list.get(i);` to get all values in finalStr  String to show in email body. also try to use `finalStr` variable as StringBuilder instead of String.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is marked as an Android question:

```
String str = TextUtils.join("\t", array_list);
```